# fazer retornar a uma parte do codigo no java

Tags: java

```
    System.out.println("digite Lançar para Rolar os dados para atirar no homem");
    P1_rolar = L.next();
    long P1_dado1 = (long) (Math.random() * 20);

    if (P1_dado1 < 21) {
        System.out.print("seu resultado é: ");

        System.out.print(P1_dado1);
        System.out.print(" e Idril errou o tiro pois estava claramente bebado quando atirou \n");

        System.out.println("Digite Lançar para Rolar os dados novamente");
        P1_rolar = L.next();
        P1_i = 0;
        while(P1_i < 2) {System.out.println("..");Thread.sleep(1000); P1_i++;}

            long P1_dado2 = (long) (Math.random() * 20);
            if(P1_dado2 < 21) {
                System.out.print("seu resultado é: ");

                    System.out.print(P1_dado2);
                System.out.print(" e Idril errou o tiro novamente \n");

                System.out.println("Digite Lançar para Rolar os dados novamente");
                P1_rolar = L.next();
                P1_i = 0;
                while(P1_i < 2) {System.out.println("..");Thread.sleep(1000); P1_i++;}


                    long P1_dado3 = (long) (Math.random() * 20);
                    if (P1_dado3 < 20) {
                        System.out.print("seu resultado é: ");
                        System.out.print(P1_dado3);
                        System.out.println("vc perdeu tente novamente ");


                       //  fazer retornar pro começo do codigo 



                    } else {System.out.println("Idril consegui acertar seu oponete com um tiro que arrancou a orelha, fazendo o homen desmaiar");}

        } else {System.out.println("Idril consegui acertar seu oponete com um tiro que arrancou a orelha, fazendo o homen desmaiar");}

    }else {System.out.println("Idril consegui acertar seu oponete com um tiro que arrancou a orelha, fazendo o homen desmaiar");}

    System.out.println("vc perdeu");
```

Comment: Forneça mais detalhes do que você precisa de ajuda, sinceramente olhando a sua pergunta não consegui compreender o que você precisa.

Comment: eu quero que se caso chegue no Terceiro if , ele retorne para o começo do código

Comment: coloca essa sua necessidade na sua pergunta, editando seu post.

Answer (score -1):

A pergunta não está muito clara, mas se eu entendi bem você pode fazer isso com um `do while`:

```
boolean tentarNovamente = false;

do
{
    System.out.println("digite Lançar para Rolar os dados para atirar no homem");
    P1_rolar = L.next();
    long P1_dado1 = (long) (Math.random() * 20);
    if (P1_dado1 < 21) 
    {
        System.out.print("seu resultado é: ");

        System.out.print(P1_dado1);
        System.out.print(" e Idril errou o tiro pois estava claramente bebado quando atirou \n");

        System.out.println("Digite Lançar para Rolar os dados novamente");
        P1_rolar = L.next();
        P1_i = 0;
        while(P1_i < 2) 
        {
            System.out.println("..");
            Thread.sleep(1000); 
            P1_i++;
        }

        long P1_dado2 = (long) (Math.random() * 20);

        if(P1_dado2 < 21) 
        {
            System.out.print("seu resultado é: ");

            System.out.print(P1_dado2);
            System.out.print(" e Idril errou o tiro novamente \n");

            System.out.println("Digite Lançar para Rolar os dados novamente");
            P1_rolar = L.next();
            P1_i = 0;
            while(P1_i < 2) 
            {
                System.out.println("..");
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
                P1_i++;
            }
            long P1_dado3 = (long) (Math.random() * 20);
            if (P1_dado3 < 20) 
            {
                System.out.print("seu resultado é: ");
                System.out.print(P1_dado3);
                System.out.println("vc perdeu tente novamente ");

                //  fazer retornar pro começo do codigo 
                tentarNovamente = true;
            } 
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Idril consegui acertar seu oponete com um tiro que arrancou a orelha, fazendo o homen desmaiar");
                tentarNovamente = false;
            }

        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Idril consegui acertar seu oponete com um tiro que arrancou a orelha, fazendo o homen desmaiar");
            tentarNovamente = false;
        }

    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Idril consegui acertar seu oponete com um tiro que arrancou a orelha, fazendo o homen desmaiar");
        tentarNovamente = false;
    }

}while(tentarNovamente);

System.out.println("vc perdeu");
```

Comment: muito obrigado.

Comment: @zDarkSword Se uma das respostas resolveu o seu problema, você pode escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la, veja [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema.

Answer (score -1):

Realmente reformular a pergunta ajudaria.
Mas pelo o que entendi você precisa que seu código seja recursivo.
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(fatorial(5));
    }

   private static int fatorial(int n){
        if(n==1)
            return n;
        return fatorial(n-1)*n;
    }
}
```